# nomenclature of some organoselenide moieties

Tags: nomenclature

what are the structures of these selenide moieties : selenenylate, selenolate ?

Can anyone tell the difference between the two in the terms of if they are anions or cations , electrophiles of nucleophiles.

Answer (score 1):

Based on usage:

- Selenenylate is a verb. It means to attach a selenium group to an organic compound - See [this passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=s76Dd3brvLMC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=selenenylate&source=bl&ots=veD6ABJQ6-&sig=z_s8pVhSYHZdMyBGm3HHmFMotkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNjI2H2MXJAhXINT4KHacCCu4Q6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=selenenylate&f=false) from *Comprehensive Organic Synthesis: Selectivity, Strategy, and Efficiency in Modern Organic Chemistry, Volume VII*

> The analogous morphinoselenamide has been shown to **selenenylate** the $\alpha$-ketoester...

- Selenolate is a noun. It is the $\ce{RSe-}$ anion, especially in ionic or coordination compounds. See various usage at the links in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenolate&oq=selenolate&aqs=chrome..69i57.5396j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)